# how to use the api() method of socialauth-android Library?

Tags: android, api, linkedin-api, socialauth

The api method of social auth library contains below parameter.

api(final String url, final String methodType, final Map params, final Map headerParams, final String body)

Please give me an example for sing this method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
    public Response api(final String url, final String methodType,
            final Map<String, String> params,
            final Map<String, String> headerParams, final String body)
            throws Exception {
        if (!isVerify) {
            throw new SocialAuthException(
                    "Please call verifyResponse function first to get Access Token");
        }
        Response response = null;
        LOG.debug("Calling URL : " + url);
        response = authenticationStrategy.executeFeed(url, methodType, params,
                headerParams, body);
        return response;
    }
```

Refer one this  [link](http://socialauth-android.googlecode.com/svn/branches/socialauth2.0/twitterplugin/src/org/brickred/socialauth/provider/TwitterImpl.java)

Comment: HI Nikhil,Thanks for ans. i know the method, but i am confused in passing parameters. what values i have to pass in params, headerParams and body string??